# Create a function and assign its return to a variable

Tags: javascript

Is there a one line way of doing this? Eg:

```
var myVare = function(params){
   if(param.condition){
       return 'a';
   }else{ 
       return 'b'; 
   }
}(param:{condition:'abc'}); 

console.log(myVare);//I would like it to be == to 'a'
```

Comment: What are you talking about? That's already a single (logical) line. You can simply strip the newlines to make it a single physical line too.

Comment: It is `myVare == 'a'` now. The if-statement inside can be "simplified" with a ternary-expression (`?:`), but *if using a function is a requirement* then "one line" is just in interpretation of the formatting.

Comment: I should not this code actually wont run.

Comment: `}(param:{condition:'abc'});`  Remove the `param:`.  `}({condition:'abc'}); `.  Also `var myVare = function(params){` should be `var myVare = function(param){`.

Comment: So, what exactly are you trying to do?  Why do you want that to be one line?

Comment: A typo sunk my boat somewhere, and Kyle's example certainly works. I wanted a one-liner because I only ever use it once, and didn't want to go define a function in my object heirarchy for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're working too hard.

```
var myVare = {condition: 'abc'}.condition ? 'a' : 'b';

console.log(myVare); // 'a'
```

Comment: Mayhap I Over simplified. I want to do more complex operations inside the assign.

Comment: Give me something more complex. Most likely your code is going to either simplify into a one-liner or deserve its own function outright.

Comment: Your right. It will work. I have to contrive something to actually do confuse myself with your example

Answer (score 0):

```
var myVare = function(param){return param.condition ? 'a' : 'b';}({condition:'abc'});
```

That's one line.  I'm not sure what you are trying to do.